# Special Characters turn to html code C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my web app, I am sending some strings from the server, and I am using them like this in my JS

```
var Texts = {
    FillAllFieldsError: '@Texts.FillAllFieldsError',
    PasswordChangeSuccess: '@Texts.PasswordChangeSuccess'
}
```

The strings which are coming from the server have some special characters like "Ø,Æ" etc.. They turn up into something with HTML code "foresp&#248;rsel".

Does anybody know how to solve it? I am using utf-8 encoding

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `@Html.Raw()` is the correct approach.

Comment: ASP Mvc will always HTML Encode any values by default.  You can use either Html.Raw or have the property value be a IHtmlString type.   So if your Texts properties were of type IHtmlString instead of string, then they would also not be encoded.  You can make any string into an IHtmlString by using MvcHtmlString.Create(string value)

Answer (score 1):

Include `System.Web` in your project to use [`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`(MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx) to decode HTML-encoded strings.

Answer (score 1):

I used this

```
@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Texts.FillAllFieldsError))
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the safest way to do what you are trying to do:

```
var Texts = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {
   Texts.FillAllFieldsError,
   Texts.PasswordChangeSuccess
});
```

*^ use an anon object if you need to specify which properties to include*

Or use an extension method like:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static class JavascriptExtensions {
   public static IHtmlString AsJavascript<T>(this T value) where T: class{
      return MvcHtmlString.Create(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
   }
}
```

Then in your view you could do this:

```
var Texts @Texts.AsJavascript();
```